# How do i interpret the output of fourier {forecast}

Tags: r, forecasting, fourier-transform

I have come across a sales forecasting problem. It involves using Fourier transformation. But I have trouble understanding the output.

what are the variables and values in the output (fplot1)? how do we interpret them? here just dates are used to create a series, sales data is not used at all.

code for reproduction

```
r1 = seq(as.Date('2013-01-01'), as.Date('2015-09-17'), by = "day")

fplot1 = as.data.frame(fourier(ts(seq_along(r1), frequency = 365), 5))

par(mfrow=c(2,3))

p1 = ts.plot(c(fplot1$S1-365, fplot1$C1-365))
p2 = ts.plot(c(fplot1$S2-365, fplot1$C2-365))
p3 = ts.plot(c(fplot1$S3-365, fplot1$C3-365))
p4 = ts.plot(c(fplot1$S4-365, fplot1$C4-365))
p5 = ts.plot(c(fplot1$S5-365, fplot1$C4-365))

head(fplot1))

      S1-365    C1-365     S2-365    C2-365     S3-365    C3-365     S4-365    C4-365    S5-365    C5-365
1 0.01721336 0.9998518 0.03442161 0.9994074 0.05161967 0.9986668 0.06880243 0.9976303 0.0859648 0.9962982
2 0.03442161 0.9994074 0.06880243 0.9976303 0.10310170 0.9946708 0.13727877 0.9905325 0.1712931 0.9852201
3 0.05161967 0.9986668 0.10310170 0.9946708 0.15430882 0.9880227 0.20510450 0.9787401 0.2553533 0.9668478
4 0.06880243 0.9976303 0.13727877 0.9905325 0.20510450 0.9787401 0.27195816 0.9623091 0.3375229 0.9413173
5 0.08596480 0.9962982 0.17129314 0.9852201 0.25535330 0.9668478 0.33752290 0.9413173 0.4171936 0.9088176
6 0.10310170 0.9946708 0.20510450 0.9787401 0.30492122 0.9523776 0.40148799 0.9158643 0.4937756 0.8695894
```

any help would be appreciated!!

plots
[image]

Comment: Pls, provide background: what is the original source of the problem? Where is the `plot()` command? As you correctly state sales data is not used at all in the generation of sine/cosine terms.

Comment: I have come across a model for predicting sales. I am trying to understand how/why Fourier transformation is used for solving this problem. https://github.com/mabrek/kaggle-rossman-store-sales/blob/master/R/data.R

Comment: anywhere that I read the problem description instead of code? Then please edit this into the question.

Comment: https://www.kaggle.com/c/rossmann-store-sales. you can download the data by clicking on "Get Data" button if needed.